# cocoa: cocoa with python

Tags: cocoa

I want to implement an Email client using python smtp library. but I don't know:
1. how to run python code in cocoa? like

```
s = smtplib.SMTP()   
s.connect("mail.yourdomain.com") 
s.login(username, password) #login if needed 
s.sendmail(mailfrom, mailto, mailbody)  
s.quit()
```

2. can cocoa can get the error message from python smtp library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the Python code into its own little program and use [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/) to run it.

[Growl's MailMe display](http://code.google.com/p/growl/source/browse/Plugins/Displays/MailMe/GrowlMailMeDisplay.m) does exactly this, for the very same purpose. It uses [my simple-mailer tool](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/simple-mailer).